# Angular 2 Animation - How to animate two routes component simultaneously when transiting from route to route?

Tags: animation, angular, angular2-routing

I know we can return a promise to `ngOnDestroy` method so that we can have enough time to animate components like fade out HTML.  However is it possible to fade out current route's HTML and fade in HTML for route going to transit next at the same time.

Inside a component:

```
export class BaseResourceComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnDeactivate {
    ...
    routerOnDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res(true), 400));
    }
}
```

I know how to do it in Angular 1, but really not sure Angular 2 support it or not.

Comment: The animation module of angular2 is not available yet. Although, according to [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr4IKlr9mhg), it will be available very soon.

Comment: I think currently you need a custom `<router-outlet>` that supports that so that the new component is added before the previous one is removed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: came here to post the same question OP has, with the added question of "Can it be done any OTHER way than writing a new router-outlet?" guess now i don't have to... Problem is `Router` is strongly referencing `<router-outlet>` so you have to replace that too... :(

Comment: I don't know but I guess not. If you want an animation where 2 components are visible at the same time, then they'll need to be in the DOM at the same time. The current router-outlet doesn't do that. It removes the old component and then adds the new one.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Okay, since `<router-outlet>` is pretty simple, I'm happy to rewrite that. Is it possible to do that and NOT rewrite (or fork) `Router` though?

Comment: It should be, but I haven't tried with the new router yet. If the implementation is public, you can just provide your implementation instead of the default one.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9350#issuecomment-227354109  for a comment about future plans in Angular2 to support this out of the box.

Comment: @aokaddaoc Are you sure you can even do that with components, like you stated with 'return a promise to `ngOnDestroy` ? I'm trying to do this now (not animation or router related), just want to delay automatic Component destruction until I resolve the promise. Can you please provide a link if possible (Angular 2 documentation doesn't state that this feature is possible) ?

Comment: @Dale Yes definitely possible, I will send you the code later

Comment: @Dale Check the updated question. If you cannot get it done, open a question and let me investigate or assist you.

Comment: @aokaddaoc Thanks for the code. Your answer seems to be `router` related. I wish to delay `Component` destruction (i.e. removal from DOM) WITHOUT router navigation. i.e. simple *ngIf toggle, or *ngFor update (without changing route) and tell Angular not to remove it from DOM until promise is resolved (see open issue [#9864](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9864) for more info)

Answer (score -2):

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// About Component Start
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Component({
  selector: 'about-cmp'
})

@View({
  template: `
    <h2 class="title">About Page</h2>
  `
})

class AboutCmp implements OnActivate, onDeactivate {

  onActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    console.log("About Page - initialized");
  }

  onDeactivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
    console.log("About Page - destroyed");
  }

}
```

Comment: This won't work, as the new one is not started until onDeactivate is finished. And once that method returns (or its promise is fulfilled), the old component will be destroyed, therefore you can't show the two at the same time.